# Labelling legend values for Axes3D chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data frame with the following values and would like to create a 3D plot showing Recency, Frequency, and Monetary values labelled by the categories/loyalty levels (bronze, silver, gold, platinum) assigned to them. The relevant data looks as follows:

`RFMScores.head()`

[image]

the `RFM_Catagory_Level` are numeric scores associated with the loyalty level

In attempting to make the chart, I used

```
figrfm2 = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(figrfm2)

xs = RFMScores.Recency
ys = RFMScores.Frequency
zs = RFMScores.Monetary
scores = RFMScores.RFM_Catagory_Level

scatter = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs,c=scores,cmap='tab20b')

ax.set_title("3D plot")
ax.set_xlabel('Recency')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_zlabel('Monetary')
ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements())
plt.show()
```

But the legend has the numeric values instead of the actual labels.

[image]

When I attempt to use the `RFM_Loyalty_Level` such as this:

```
figrfm2 = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(figrfm2)

xs = RFMScores.Recency
ys = RFMScores.Frequency
zs = RFMScores.Monetary

scatter = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs,c=RFMScores.RFM_Loyalty_Level,cmap='tab20b')

ax.set_title("3D plot")
ax.set_xlabel('Recency')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_zlabel('Monetary')
ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements())
plt.show()
```

The chart is blank with no data. How do I fix this so that I have a chart, but with the label categories "**platinum, gold, silver, bronze**" instead of the numeric values that are in the legend?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532115/set-scatter-plot-legend-labels-with-legend-elements)

The key (no pun intended) is to create a dictionary of the two columns and then pass in the handles and keys into the `legend(handles=,labels=)` arguments. Solution is below, but check out link for the original answer and to give credit to where it's properly due.

```
grouped_codes = dict(zip(RFMScores.RFM_Loyalty_Level, RFMScores.RFM_Catagory_Level))

figrfm2 = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(figrfm2)

xs = RFMScores.Recency
ys = RFMScores.Frequency
zs = RFMScores.Monetary
scores = RFMScores.RFM_Catagory_Level

scatter = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs,c=scores,cmap='tab20b')
handles = scatter.legend_elements(num=[1,2,3,4])[0]

ax.set_title("3D plot")
ax.set_xlabel('Recency')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_zlabel('Monetary')
ax.legend(title="Binned RFM Scores",handles=handles,labels=grouped_codes.keys(),*scatter.legend_elements())
plt.show()
```